# Create admob native advance ad id

Tags: android, admob, native-ads

I have implemented advance native ads in my Android application.

Now, I want to take them live but cannot get them to work with my native app unit id. I am guessing it's because that can only be used for express ads.

How can I get an advance ad unit id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Native Ads Advanced are in a closed beta right now. From [Native Ads Advanced](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-advanced):

> This feature is currently in a limited beta release. If you are
>   interested in participating, reach out to your account manager to
>   discuss the possibility. This feature will be made available to all
>   publishers at the conclusion of the beta.

You need to contact AdMob if you'd like to participate in the beta.

Comment: Is there any email where I can ask to participate in the beta because I cannot get any infromation on their web site.

Comment: @TadejVengust I'd use their Support page to contact them: https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: anyone able to get the native advanced ad id?